# Comment traduire « hipster » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, argot

C'est un mot anglais, plutôt argotique, qui représente une catégorie de personnes qui se caractérisent comme des libre-penseurs, allant à contre-courant de la culture et aimant un style d'art progressif. Une description plus complète peut être trouvée en anglais [ici](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hipster).

Quel mot, en français, décrit le mieux ce type de personnes ? « Anticonformiste » m'est venu en tête, mais c'est un peu paradoxal d'avoir un « courant anticonformiste ».

Comment: 'hipster' est un néologisme des années 40, recyclés depuis quelques années pour désigner un courant de mode plus ou moins générationnel (comme en leur temps "zazou", "beatnik", "baba cool" etc. etc.). Il ne se traduit pas. Demander une traduction est un peu comme demander une traduction de "baba cool" ou n'importe lequel de ces termes inventés en territoire anglophone dont la sémantique s'est depuis longtemps détachée de l'étymologie... Toutes les mentions francophones que j'ai rencontrées jusqu'à présent utilisent le terme original.

Comment: @Dave Donc d'après toi, la traduction de « hipster » est « hipster », ça me va.

Comment: It should be noted that the OP has not accurately represented the meaning of the word in English. The term 'hipster' has been made to sound like a very positive thing, whereas in fact it is generally negative. While it is true that hipsters are associated with those things, the connotation is that they do it to be cool, to be different, not because it's genuinely who they are. They do it to be "hip," hence the term.

Comment: Hipster c'est un peu comme être en avance sur son temps, http://9gag.com/gag/3350452 "I was.... before it was cool "

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas pouvoir utiliser le mot marginal pour traduire hipster?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On parle de courants (et de contre-courants) anticonformistes mais le terme ne convient pas pour rendre *hipster* sans précisions supplémentaires. C'est un contre courant à la culture dominante, certes, mais il y a tellement de courants et contre-courants que c'est insuffisant.

Perso je n'ai jamais traduit et toujours dit *[hipster](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipster)*...

On pourrait peut-être dire [baba cool](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/baba_cool) qui garde la référence aux hippies et à la musique contenue dans *[hipster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipster_%28contemporary_subculture%29)*, mais il y a dans *[hipster](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hipster)* l'idée importante d'être *à la mode* (*trendy* qui figure dans les définitions en anglais de [hipster](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hipster)), qu'il n'y a pas vraiment dans *baba cool*.

Peut-être que [bobo](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourgeois-boh%C3%A8me) conviendrait mieux pour la référence à la mode ?

La presse française utilise le mot hipster. Sur le web :

- http://lociol.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/dans-la-peau-dun-hipster/
- http://www.frenchinlondon.com/blog-francais-londres/2010/10/mode-fashion-london-les-hipsters-de-londres-sont-ils-ringards-danger/
- http://cultiz.com/blog/cest-quoi-un-hipster/

Comment: *Bobo* est le meilleur équivalent imho, mais c'est plutôt un équivalent culturel que linguistique, pour autant que cette phrase ait du sens.

Comment: Merci pour ton commentaire explicatif. Au final, je retiens qu'il n'y a pas de traduction. J'utiliserai donc « hipster » comme « new age » ou « grunge », dans sa forme originelle.

Comment: Les bobos et les hipster sont fondamentalement différents, car les hipsters étaient des bobos avant que ces derniers n'existent.

Comment: Si vous ne comprenez pas mon commentaire précédent, vous n'êtes pas un hipster, ou vous ne passez pas la journée à procrastiner sur 9gag.

Comment: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9trosexuel

Comment: comment on peut être contre-courant et à la mode?

Comment: @Nikko -- C'est dans la *nature* de la mode d'etre contre la mode precedente/actuelle. ;-) "Courant" = "mode", et les deux sont toujours poses contre le statut quo. Etre nonconformiste est autre chose pourtant ; c'est etre contre le tendence de suivre une mode etc.

Answer (score 9):

et pourquoi pas cette version : hipster = branchouille ?

Comment: +1 Il y a de ça.

Answer (score 6):

La description de [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipster_%28contemporary_subculture%29) est plus fiable et plus complète. « Anticonformiste » ne convient vraiment pas, le courant hipster est une réaction à une culture bien particulière, avec son propre conformisme (par la musique, les vêtements, etc. — comme n'importe quel mouvement culturel).

En pratique, le mouvement n'est pas vraiment identifiable en tant que tel dans les pays francophones. La seule traduction raisonnablement compréhensible est *hipster* (prononcé `/ipstœʁ/` ou `/ipstɛʁ/`).

Answer (score 2):

Dans Wikipedia, il est écrit, "qui adoptaient l'attitude..." en gros il est question de gens qui ont avant tout besoin d'adopter l'attitude d'autres pour donner un sens à leur existence. Gens sans grande personnalité probablement et qui s'ennuient dès qu'ils sont seuls, face à eux-mêmes. Alors ils veulent être « tendance », user de mots anglais à tout bout de champ, pour faire  « bien », pour avoir l'impression d'appartenir à la même caste, de gens qui usent du même langage. Mais ils se disent anti-conformistes, mmmmm! Je doute!!!
Mais peu leur importe, ils n'y pensent pas le moins du monde, qu'ils sont complétement conformistes, ils ne veulent simplement ne pas y croire. C'est pour eux une honte d'être considérés un peu comme les autres. Il leur faut des marques, entendez des repères sur lesquels se tenir et qui les départageront des autres. Mais ces autres leur ressemblent dans le fond. Ils ne vont simplement jamais dans le fond.

Answer (score 1):

Une rapide enquête dans les cafés de la Bastille (PARIS XI°) pourrait se conclure par :

> **Hypster** : Frimeur qui s'la pète.

Serait en accord avec le commentaire de Aerovistae ou *frimeur* indique le comportement superficiel et ostentatoire et "se la péter" indique une surestime clinquante du soi et de ses capacités.

Pour d'autres contextes, le français récèle d'anciennes définitions :

> Hypster : **Incroyable** : Sobriquet donné sous le Directoire aux jeunes gens fortunés, généralement royalistes, qui se distinguaient par des tenues excentriques (Dictionnaire encyclopédique alpha).

On prononçait *Incôyâble* omettant le *r* grossier, gascon.
Au temps de l'argent roi en période bling-bling, la définition convient parfaitement.

"Là où les idées manquent, un mot arrive toujours à temps"(Goethe) :

> Hypster :
>   - **néobobo**
>   - **metrosexuel néobobo**

pour une traduction à la mode, tendance, dans le vent (comme on disait au siècle dernier).

Pour ce qui concerne la relation à la *com'* (ancienne attitude *m'as-tu-vu*) :

Hypster : **snob cosmopolite** - "Snob : qui admire sans limites ni discernement les manières, les goûts, les modes en usages dans les milieux dits distingués - Le petit Robert", cosmopolite se limitant aux pays à fort niveau de vie.

Ils pourraient se 'valoriser' d'être *les premiers snobs cosmopolites du troisième millénaire*.

Pour aimer les mots et s'en amuser (et donner de l'ouvrage aux philologues à venir), va-t-on voir les gros titres :

- *Hipsters* : doit-on ajouter la filière *hipster* au programme Erasmus?
- Un *hipster* directeur de recherches au C.N.R.S.(Centre Néo-tout des Répétitions Socio-comportementales)
- L'avenir des *hipsters* est-il abêtissant comme celui des bourgeois de Jacques Brel?
- *Hipstérisme* : est-ce une cinglitude dépravée, une absence de créativité douloureuse ou une insuffisance intellectuelle arrogante?
- L'internationale *hipster*, quel avenir?

Comment: trouvé récemment : *h[y|i]pster* http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hypster

Answer (score 0):

Hipster ne se traduit pas.

C'est quelqu'un qui fait les choses différemment, contre les courants du moment (par exemple la mode), juste pour se faire remarquer, même si ce comportement différent n'est pas vraiment dans sa nature.

*Rétrograde* peut s'appliquer aussi pour certaines utilisations

Simple.